# Is it possible to log the request body size in AWS API Gateway?

Tags: aws-api-gateway, amazon-sqs, amazon-cloudwatch

I have an API Gateway -> SQS integration where every request writes the request body as an SQS message. Since the maximum size for SQS messages is 256kb I'd like to have an alert when the request size is larger than this threshold. Is that possible?

I see it's possible to log the response size but not the request.

Answer (score 0):

Api Gateway Logs will show an error message , if we have enable `Enable CloudWatch Logs` and `Log full requests/responses data` at Api Gateway Stage.

```
{
    "Error": {
        "Code": "InvalidParameterValue",
        "Message": "One or more parameters are invalid. Reason: Message must be shorter than 262144 bytes.",
        "Type": "Sender"
    },
    "RequestId": "b410da48-7fee-5c2e-b046-82ed9a872753"
}
```

Then we can create a cloudwatch metric filter on `Message must be shorter` to trigger an alert.

Comment: That's not what I'm seeing. I sent a 750k binary request body and the logs for API Gateway show success, even though the message is not visible in the queue, presumably because it's too large.

Comment: Interesting. I tested it by passing a large Json body, it failed and printed this log. Something in correct in api gateway setting?

Comment: Quite possibly, but I can't figure out what. Maybe in the integration settings, but then it wouldn't have an effect on the logs.